# How to add another bulk operation?

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Jira allows to add web fragments on [different locations](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Web+Fragments#WebFragments-Locations).

I'd like to write a plugin that adds another bulk operation but can neither find a location (if this done via a web fragement at all) nor a hint in the [Jira Plugin Module Types](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Plugin+Module+Types) how to add such an operation. From existing plugins (e.g. exporter) I got the impression that there must be a way.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong about you question but unless some jira support is among us on SO I think it'd be better to ask their support which I think is very good.

Comment: Well, I hope that I'm not the only one and some more experienced developers are here :-)

Comment: I read a question about this on answers.atlassian.com a few days ago

Comment: Thanks, here's what I found: [Any doc/guideline to create a new BulkOperation in JIRA ?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/208792/answers/11970910) and [Bulk operations on Issues in JIRA](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/18948), though maybe not that straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it, here is what I did:

I extended `AbstractBulkOperation` class and used approach with `EventListener` to add this operation in `afterPropertiesSet` like this:

```
ComponentAccessor.getBulkOperationManager().addBulkOperation(MyOperationClass.NAME_KEY, MyOperationClass.class);
```

You need to implement `canPerform`, `perform` (the actual operation), `getOperationName`, `getCannotPerformMessageKey`, `getNameKey`, `getDescriptionKey`

I extended `AbstractBulkOperationDetailsAction`, but `BulkEditBeanSessionHelper` couldn't be autowired so I introduced protected constructor and got it there:

```
protected MyActionClass()
{
super(null, ComponentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(BulkEditBeanSessionHelper.class));

genericBulkWatchOperation = ComponentAccessor.getBulkOperationManager().getOperation(NAME_KEY);
}
```

You need to implement `getOperationDetailsActionName`, `doDetails`,`doDetailsValidation`, `doPerform` methods in this class.

I created `Webwork` element in `atlassian-plugin.xml`, something like this:

```
<webwork1 key="key" name="name" class="java.lang.Object">
<actions>
<action name="path to action class" alias="Action">
<command name="details" alias="ActionDetails">
<view name="success">/secure/views/bulkedit/bulkchooseoperation.jsp</view>
<view name="input">/secure/views/bulkedit/bulkActiondetails.jsp</view>
<view name="error">/secure/views/bulkedit/bulkchooseoperation.jsp</view>
</command>
<command name="detailsValidation" alias="ActionDetailsValidation">
<view name="input">/secure/views/bulkedit/bulkActionconfirmation.jsp</view>
<view name="error">/secure/views/bulkedit/bulkActionconfirmation.jsp</view>
</command>
<command name="perform" alias="ActionPerform">
<view name="error">/secure/views/bulkedit/bulkActionerror.jsp</view>
</command>
</action>
</actions>
</webwork1>
```

JSP files cannot be embedded in plugin, I deployed them to `/secure/views/bulkedit`

To wrap it up - you need 3 classes (`Operation`, `Action` and `EventListener`), `webwork` definition in atlassian-plugin.xml and `Event Listener` definition also in atlassian-plugin.xml. Then you need JSP files. You can take existing ones and use them as an example.
Basically I took `WatchIssue` operation files and did it analogically.

**I strongly suggest to take a look at JIRA code to see how they do it.**